# installer Problem in iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I developed on audio based application, when i drag and drop .app file into the iTunes its not at all showing in iTunes application list.

The application size is 177 Mb.

Is there any problem with the size.

Please help me out in this issue.

thanks in advance.

Satya.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe size is the problem (much larger apps than that are allowed, i believe 2Gb, just not over 3G).

Anyway, did you set up a distribution certificate and edit your entitlements correctly? I belive [this link](http://bluxte.net/musings/2009/05/17/ad-hoc-distribution-iphone-application) will help you.

Comment: No, m not distributing the application, sending installer only.

Comment: I believe this is what is called ad-hoc distribution. I believe that you need to do the entitlement magic in order to get iTunes to accept the executable, otherwise you need to load it using Xcode.